# Online Revocation Checking Using Custom Root in X509Chain

Tags: .net, vb.net, security, x509certificate

I need to validate a leaf certificate using a root certificate that is not stored in the Trusted Root CA store. This works perfectly fine using `X509Chain` with the `X509ChainPolicy.RevocationMode` set to `X509RevocationMode.NoCheck` and the `X509ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags` set to include the flag `X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority`. I provide my root certificate to the X509Chain by using `X509Chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore`.

There becomes an issue when I want to check the revocation status of the leaf certificate. The leaf certificate provides the CRL distribution point, but when using `X509RevocationMode.Online`, I get these statuses: `X509ChainStatusFlags.RevocationStatusUnknown` and `X509ChainStatusFlags.OfflineRevocation`.

If I install the root into the Trusted Root CA store, the revocation check works just fine. As mentioned however, my application will not be installing these into the cert store.

Here's how I am attempting to do this currently:

```
Dim certChain As New X509Chain
certChain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online
certChain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EndCertificateOnly
certChain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority Or X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreNotTimeValid
certChain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(rootCertificate)

Dim blnValid As Boolean = certChain.Build(certificate)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible prior to .NET 5.

.NET 5 introduced custom root trust to X509Chain which supports this, you'd add

```
certChain.ChainPolicy.TrustMode = X509ChainTrustMode.CustomRootTrust;
certChain.ChainPolicy.CustomTrustStore.Add(rootCert);
```

which then replaces the root trust list for that chain with the specified certificate(s).

But the system will not download, or process from the cache, revocation from an untrusted authority.  Your only options with older .NET are

- Register your cert as trusted
- Not care about revocation
- Use another chain provider (P/Invoking into the OS libraries, or using a third party library).